# Cant find DatePicker in WPF

Tags: wpf, vb.net, datepicker

I am using visual studio 2008.
I am learning WPF.
I want to have a Masked TextBox or DatePicker in WPF.
But I don't find them in toolbox.

I have tried to Reset the toolbox but still cant find it.
I have also tried to choose control from .NET Library but there also no control found named DatePicker for WPF.

Comment: WPF 1.0 did not come with a datepicker or masked textbox. I recommend the [WPF toolkit](http://wpf.codeplex.com/releases/view/40535) for the DatePicker. You'll have to find a MaskedTextBox. Or just use Visual Studio 2012.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I will try it and let you know.

Comment: "Rather than adding references,I suggest you to right click the toolbox in the designer window and click "Choose Items".Go to WPF components and select "Browse" and add WPFToolkit.VisualStudio.Design assembly from there.click ok and I hope it will load the necessary toolbox components successfully."
source: [MSDN Forum](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vswpfdesigner/thread/781ed3ba-a2f1-4f50-b50e-b772ceaeebe1)

Comment: I was incorrect about the version numbers, which follow the .NET versioning. WPF 3.0 and 3.5 did not include the DatePicker - these were introduced in WPF 4.0. The MaskedTextBox is available through the [Extended WPF Toolkit](http://wpftoolkit.codeplex.com/) which is dependent on .NET 4.0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The WPF 1.0 does not provide such controls.
I highly recommend you the [WPF Toolkit](http://wpf.codeplex.com/).

Comment: Note that the WPF Toolkit does not include a MaskedTextBox. The [Extended WPF Toolkit](http://wpftoolkit.codeplex.com/) does, but that is dependent on .NET 4.0 and you'd probably have trouble getting it to compile in Visual Studio 2008 (though I've never tried).